# Laravel PhpSpreadsheet Multiple Table Import

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpspreadsheet

i want to ask, is it possible to import excel [excel to import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kZoY.jpg)

to the database like [database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zeaz.jpg) in php laravel?

Comment: Please don't use images as image hosting can delete it any time.

Answer (score 0):

of course there is a excelent package for import and export data from excel

[Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel)

here is an example for export excel

```
class PermissionExport implements FromCollection, ShouldQueue , WithMapping , WithHeadings, WithEvents
{

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [

            BeforeSheet::class  =>function(BeforeSheet $event){
                $event->getDelegate()->setRightToLeft(true);
            }
        ];
    }


    public function collection()
    {
        return Permission::all();
    }

    public function map($permissions): array
    {
        return [
            $permissions->name,
            $permissions->label,
        ];
    }


    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'permission name',
            'permission description',
        ];
    }
}
```

and here is and example for import data from excel

```
class PermissionsImport implements ToModel,WithStartRow
{
    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new permission([
            'name'     => $row[0],
            'label'    => $row[1],
        ]);
    }

    public function startRow(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```